# Accessing has_many from scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I have the following models:

```rb
class ServiceProvider < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :versions, class_name: "ServiceProviderVersion"
end
```

```rb
class ServiceProviderVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service_provider
  has_many :service_provider_roles, :through => :service_provider_to_role_maps
  scope :effective, -> { where("effective_date <= ?", Time.now).order('effective_date desc') }
end
```

```rb
class ServiceProviderToRoleMap < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service_provider_version
  belongs_to :service_provider_role   
end
```

```rb
class ServiceProviderRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  has_many :service_provider_versions, :through => :service_provider_to_role_maps
  has_many :service_provider_to_role_maps, :dependent => :destroy 
end
```

Now I am trying to get all the service providers which are effective and belongs to a particular role. Ideally, I'd like to do the following

```
ServiceProviderVersion.effective.by_role('Admin')
```

But since, `ServiceProviderVersion.effective` returns more than a record, I am not able to define a scope on ServiceProviderVersion which will filter by role.

Is there any way to achieve this? I am using Rails4

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
class ServiceProviderRole < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :by_role, ->(name) { where(name: name) }

class ServiceProviderVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :by_role, ->(name) { joins(:service_provider_roles).merge(ServiceProviderRole.by_role(name)) }
```

Then you can call:

```
ServiceProviderVersion.effective.by_role('Admin')
```